# Unable to convert java.util.List<java.lang.Object> to java.util.List<java.nio.file.Path> due to "incompatible types" error in Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins

I am getting a COMPILATION ERROR by Jenkins:

> incompatible types: `java.util.List<java.lang.Object>` cannot be converted to `java.util.List<java.nio.file.Path>`

In the line :
`collectList =  dirList.collect(Collectors.toList());`

In the method below:

```
public String getMostRecentFolder(String parentFolder){                                                  

        List<Path> collectList = null;
        Path path = null;
        Path pathName = null;

        Stream<Path> dirList = null;
        try {
            dirList = Files.list(Paths.get(parentFolder)).sorted(new Comparator<Path>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Path path1, Path path2) {
                    Long file1Name = path1.toFile().lastModified();
                    Long file2Name = path2.toFile().lastModified();
                    return file2Name.compareTo(file1Name);

                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.error("getMostRecentFolder failed with exception: " + e);
        }
        try {
            collectList =  dirList.collect(Collectors.toList());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.error("getMostRecentFolder failed with exception: " + e);
        }
        try {
            path = (Path) collectList.get(0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.error("getMostRecentFolder failed with exception: " + e);
        }
        try {
            pathName = path.getFileName();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.error("getMostRecentFolder failed with exception: " + e);
        }       
        return pathName.toString().trim();
    }
```

Comment: Try map.values() for that collector

Comment: Does only Jenkins complain, but your IDE compiles fine? Do they both use teh same Java version to compile?

Comment: One question: Why do you have to add a cast here: `path = (Path) collectList.get(0)`? Are you able to remove that `(Path)`? If not, your definition of `collectList` must be different from `List<Path> collectList`.

Comment: Where in  the code I can use map.values() ?

Comment: Yes, Only Jenkins complaint. in my eclipse I have java 1.8 , I'm not sure what java version Jenkins uses

Comment: I did remove the casting , but the problem still exists.

Answer (score 1):

try this one. i don't get error on this code.
i just replaced parameter with "." and logger with println to make it run in a main method. you can undo these changes.

```
    List<Path> collectList = null;
    Path path = null;
    Path pathName = null;

    Stream<Path> dirList = null;
    try {
        dirList = Files.list(Paths.get(".")).sorted((p1, p2) -> ((Long) p1.toFile().lastModified()).compareTo(p2.
                toFile().lastModified()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("err");
    }
    try {
        collectList = dirList.collect(Collectors.toList());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("err");
    }
    try {
        path = (Path) collectList.get(0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("err");
    }
    try {
        pathName = path.getFileName();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("err");
    }
```

in java 8 you can use lambdas. if you have to use some version before java 1.8
then replace lambda expression with anonymous inner class like this.

```
    List<Path> collectList = null;
    Path path = null;
    Path pathName = null;
    Stream<Path> dirList = null;
    try {
        dirList = Files.list(Paths.get(".")).sorted(new Comparator<Path>()
        {
            @Override
            public int compare(Path p1, Path p2)
            {
                return ((Long) p1.toFile().lastModified()).compareTo(p2.
                        toFile().lastModified());
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("err");
    }
    try {
        collectList = dirList.collect(Collectors.toList());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("err");
    }
    try {
        path = (Path) collectList.get(0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("err");
    }
    try {
        pathName = path.getFileName();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("err");
    }
```

Comment: Got error: lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.7
17:00:25   (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions) . In lite   dirList = ......

Comment: the exception can be solved by replacing the lambda with an anonymous class. but i suggest upgrading to java 8, it is compatible with previous versions so old codes still work, but lots of new features including functional programming are available.